# How many OUTPUT parameters can we declare for a stored procedure in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, out-parameters

How many OUTPUT parameters can we declare for a stored procedure in SQL Server ?

Comment: If you have to ask, you've got too many :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258259%28SQL.80%29.aspx), a stored procedure can have a maximum of 2,100 parameters. The limit applies across all parameters, regardless of their direction (input or output).

However, I would advice you to keep the number of parameters relatively low. If you're returning many pieces of data or a lot of data, consider using a result set instead.

Answer (score 2):

Basically almost as many as you like ;-)

If you check this Technet article [Maximum Capacity Specifications for SQL Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx), the maximum number of parameters for a stored procedure is 2'100. I don't see any mention whether or not you couldn't have all 2100 being output parameters, if you really must......

Answer (score 2):

2100 as per [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258259(SQL.80).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You're only limited by the number of parameters a stored procedure can have which is 2100 (SQL 2005/2008).

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx):

> A stored procedure can have a maximum
>   of 2,100 parameters